# NoSuchMethodError when using com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, google-signin

When trying to integrate Google Sign-in with an Android app, I experienced `NoSuchMethod` errors when trying to launch the app.  I traced the error to the inclusion of the `com.google.gms.google-services` plugin in my `build.gradle`.  However, I was not able to figure out how to fix the problem short of removing the gradle plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the `com.google.gms.google-services` plugin was including a version of `play-services-measurement` that didn't match the version of the other Google Play Services dependencies in my app.  By manually adding

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0'
```

to my `build.gradle`, I was able to resolve the problem.

Why Google requires that dependency, and what it does with it is a question for another day.